# How to style custom search suggestion list in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I implemented custom suggestions by content provider based on [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html); it works, however I have a problem styling the suggestion list. The suggestion list I currently have has black background and white text. I want to change it to white background and black text. I did some search online and tried something like this in styles.xml file:

```
<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/list_item_search_suggestion</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

My list_item_search_suggestion looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    tools:text="Blah blah blah"/>
```

However, when I run the app and search something, it crashes before the suggestion list shows up. I get a NullPointerException from newView method in SuggestionsAdapter. This SuggestionAdapter is from SDK, I'm not implementing my own adapter. I just implement the content provider and set that in searchable.xml. Also the stack track is something like this:

```
06-15 21:11:09.253    4063-4063/com.tophatter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tophatter, PID: 4063
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.newView(SuggestionsAdapter.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.getView(SuggestionsAdapter.java:453)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1585)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1167)
        at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:554)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1096)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:971)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:953)
        at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the stack trace.

Comment: Please post your code of adapter and the view which you are inflating so that I can help you

Comment: Same here, I'd like to apply the "light" theme to the suggestion row, maintaining AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar for the searchview widget. Can you please post your list_item_search_suggestion layout?

Comment: @Skynet, I updated my question. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. Basically SuggestionsAdapter is referring some widgets I was not providing in my custom suggestion row layout. So I copied default custom suggestion row layout from source code and changed background and text color as my custom layout. It's working now.

Comment: Doing this way does highlight on suggestion row works correctly?

Comment: Where did you get it?

Comment: can you please provide any code? i cant understand how can i do this?

Comment: He got it from:
file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml